# Automatic Scale down on AWS of Spring Boot Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to deploy a Spring Boot application on Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The application is a back-end service which exposes a REST API. My concern is what happens when AWS has the automatic scaling enabled. I try with an example:

1. An instance starts with the application
2. I call the REST API which activates the process (it can take 20 minutes to be completed)
3. AWS scales out creating a new instance so that new requests can be processed by this new instance
4. After a while, AWS decides to reduce the number of instances - scale in, because the memory (or CPU, or Network out, or...) usage is lower than the lower limit

Does AWS check if the application is working? I'd like to avoid that it kills one instance while the application is working (loss of data, job interruption, ...).

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate AWS Auto Scaling Lifecycle Hooks which will allow your application to be notified (via CloudWatch, SNS, or SQS) when AWS wants to scale down its instance and take the appropriate action, including delaying the restart.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html